# JSON Objects in Swift 5 using Swift JSON, how can i make a JSON object like this :

Tags: ios, json, swift, object, swifty-json

How to create a Json object like this

```
{
  "child": {
    "0": 0,
    "1": 0
  },
  "child_age": {    
    "0": [0],
    "1":[0]
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you encounter any problems while making it?

Comment: how can i make the key of Json object like "0" or "1" in swift language???

Comment: Literally `"0"` and `"1"`. Did you try? If you did, what error did you get?

Comment: i am using struct Codable object to represent it like :                                      
  struct child_age : Codable {
    var key = [Int]()
    
} . but how i set the key is "0" or  "1"??

Comment: when i write  let childAge = child_age(key: "0", value: [0]) the result of Json represented like   "child_age":{ 
      "key":"0",
      "value":[ 
         0
      ]
   } but i want to this value "0" : [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Codable` you can define your struct like this

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let child: [String: Int]
    let childAge: [String: [Int]]
}
```

And use it like this

```
let root = Root(child: ["0": 0, "1": 0], childAge: ["0": [0], "1": [0]])

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase

do {
    let data = try encoder.encode(root)
    if let json = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        //...
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Yeap! That works and it's also the shortest one! Thanks